# Liftweb form processing

Tags: scala, lift

How do I test to see which option is in focus during a form submittal?

```
<select name="temp" id="keys">
   <option selected="selected" value="ISBN">ISBN</option>
   <option value="Title">Title</option>
   <option value="Author">Author</option>
   <option value="Publisher">Publisher</option>
   <option value="Date">Date</option>
</select>
```

From my snippet I've tried S.param("temp")...

Comment: Did you have any problem with using S.param?

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is use `SHtml.select()`

This way you can have the options taken from Scala code, in a typesafe manner and prone to typos.

As far as I understand, `S.param("temp")` should work also, if you din't mess with the `<form>`.